# cannot import name is_secure_transport

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-social-auth

I am using python-social-auth API for authentication in my website.
But I am getting an exception `cannot import name is_secure_transport.

Below is the trace.

```
Django 1.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'social.apps.django_app.default',
 'login')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/apps/django_app/utils.py" in wrapper
  49.                                                backend, uri)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/apps/django_app/utils.py" in load_backend
  29.     Backend = get_backend(BACKENDS, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/backends/utils.py" in get_backend
  51.         load_backends(backends, force_load=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/backends/utils.py" in load_backends
  33.             backend = module_member(auth_backend)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/utils.py" in module_member
  23.     module = import_module(mod)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/utils.py" in import_module
  17.     __import__(name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/backends/facebook.py" in <module>
  12. from social.backends.oauth import BaseOAuth2
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/backends/oauth.py" in <module>
  4. from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/__init__.py" in <module>
  3. from .oauth2_auth import OAuth2
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests_oauthlib/oauth2_auth.py" in <module>
  3. from oauthlib.oauth2 import is_secure_transport

Exception Type: ImportError at /login/google-oauth2/
Exception Value: cannot import name is_secure_transport
```

Comment: My guess is, you might have an older version of `oauthlib` Try upgrading it to 0.6.x

Comment: thanx @karthikr upgrading worked for me ... now getting `HTTPError at /complete/google-oauth2/
401 Client Error: Unauthorized` any idea...

Comment: make sure you have provided the correct credentials as defined in the documentation

Comment: Having same issue. I have upgraded oauthlib to 0.6.1.

Comment: @ShashankHegde hope that worked  for you.. :-)

Comment: @HadeS : Thanks it worked for me. I upgraded it to 0.7 :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Updating the oauthlib version definitely works.

Just do this:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade oauthlib
```

Answer (score 7):

you should uninstall tweepy, upgrade oauthlib and then reinstall tweepy as root:

```
sudo pip uninstall tweepy
sudo pip install oauthlib --upgrade
sudo apt-get install python-tweepy
```

Had the same problem and this worked fine for me.

Comment: This sorted me out. I recently had to upgrade tweepy because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18580472/3563897. Turns out I then needed to do the full overhaul to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Having tried a few other things (including the accepted answer) this is what fixed it for me